# IntelliJ Plugin Development position

Tags: node.js, plugins, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

I try to create an IntelliJ plugin (and I'm new to IntelliJ dev) to add a new project template for NodeJS and want to add it here

[image]

Here is the plugin.xml, for now it's appear under Static Web but don't know why

```
<idea-plugin version="2">
  <id>com.jaumard.plugin</id>
  <name>My Plugin</name>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <vendor email="support@yourcompany.com" url="http://www.yourcompany.com">YourCompany</vendor>

  <description><![CDATA[
      Enter short description for your plugin here.<br>
      <em>most HTML tags may be used</em>
    ]]></description>

  <change-notes><![CDATA[
      Add change notes here.<br>
      <em>most HTML tags may be used</em>
    ]]>
  </change-notes>

  <idea-version since-build="131"/>

    <depends>NodeJS</depends>
    <depends>JavaScript</depends>
  <depends>com.intellij.modules.platform</depends>

  <extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
    <!-- Add your extensions here -->
    <codeInsight.template.postfixTemplateProvider language="PluginJS"
                                                  implementationClass="com.intellij.codeInsight.template.postfix.templates.EmptyPostfixTemplateProvider"/>
      <errorHandler implementation="com.intellij.diagnostic.ITNReporter"/>
    <applicationService serviceInterface="com.jaumard.settings.PluginJSConfig"
                        serviceImplementation="com.jaumard.settings.PluginJSConfig"/>

    <directoryProjectGenerator implementation="com.jaumard.PluginJSProjectGenerator"/>
    <projectTemplatesFactory implementation="com.jaumard.PluginJSTemplateFactory"/>
  </extensions>


</idea-plugin>
```